# Appending data from one sheet to another Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I know a bit of VBA, however I got a problem, I am trying to write a code that will copy all data from 1 sheet, append/paste it into the next blank cell in sheet 2 and then remove the data from sheet 1. I am using below code, but I get cell values replaced by the word TRUE.

```
Sub Instal_Sum_Paste()

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Vehicle working").Select

  Dim N As Long
  N = Cells(6, 2).End(xlDown).Row
  Set DT = Range("b6:G" & N)
  DT.Copy

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Installation Summary").Select
  lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
  ActiveCell.Value = DT.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Vehicle working").Select
  DT.Select
  Selection.ClearContents

  MsgBox "done", vbOKOnly, "done"

End Sub
```

Comment: This line here: `ActiveCell.Value = DT.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)` is not doing what you intended. It is actually pasting the values in range 'DT' in the same spot and then pasting the result of that action (ie TRUE) in the activecell. What you wanted to do was `ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)` which is pasting the copied range at the active cell.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find an answer, its silly I know:

```
 Sub Instal_Sum_Paste()

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Vehicle working").Select

  Dim N As Long
  N = Cells(6, 2).End(xlDown).Row
  Set DT = Range("b6:G" & N)
  DT.Select
  Selection.Copy

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Installation Summary").Select
  lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Vehicle working").Select
  DT.Select
  Selection.ClearContents

  MsgBox "done", vbOKOnly, "done"

End Sub
```